# convert list of dict to dict of dict

Tags: python, python-3.x

How could in convert a list of `dict` to a `dict` of `dict`.

This is the list I have:

```
data = [{'id': '7249722264','title':'test'}, {'id': '111','test':'te11111st'}]
```

I have to pass this dataset to an api that accept data in this format:

```
api_data = {'fields': {'id': '72497264', 'title': 'test'}}
```

I need to loop through the element present in the data list and pass it to api like this:

for each record in the list:

```
new_dict = {'fields': {'id': '72497264', 'title': 'test'}}
api.post(new_dict)
```

How I can achieve this? Thanks

Comment: why there is `test` instead of `title` in 2nd element of dictionary? What should be output in such cases?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like so with a `for` loop:

```
data = [{'id': '7249722264','title':'test'}, {'id': '111','test':'te11111st'}]
new_dict = {}
for e, i in enumerate(data):
  new_dict['fields'+str(e)] = i

print(new_dict)

>>> {'fields0': {'id': '72497264', 'title': 'test'}, 'fields1': {'id': '111','test':'te11111st'}}
```

But you can't name every key `fields` because dict keys are unique, so you would have to either make the API call each time inside the `for` loop, or as I've done above append an index to the key name.

Edit: Alternative dict comprehension (courtesey of Dillon Davis):

```
data = [{'id': '7249722264','title':'test'}, {'id': '111','test':'te11111st'}]
new_dict = {'fields{}'.format(i):x for i, x in enumerate(data)}
print(new_dict)

    >>> {'fields0': {'id': '72497264', 'title': 'test'}, 'fields1': {'id': '111','test':'te11111st'}}
```

Comment: As a dict comprehension- `new_dict = {'fields{}'.format(i):x for i, x in enumerate(data)}`

Comment: @taurus05 they're equivalent, but I figure its nice to have options. I usually lean towards comprehensions for their speed and to avoid nesting-bloat, but everyone has their own preferences.

Comment: Thanks Matt & Dillon